# Error al conectar firebase con flutter error use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Tags: firebase, flutter, vscode

Intenté conectar `firebase` con `flutter`, hice lo que dice la documentación y pues todo bien, pero al momento de correr la aplicación me sale el siguiente error.

> warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

¿Alguna idea de como se puede solucionar?, es que me sale para solucionarlo pero es Visual Studio y yo estoy usando es Visual Studio Code y no me sale la opción que dicen en la solución.

Comment: _Consider using strncpy_s instead_... ¿O es que acaso no usás `strncpy`?

Comment: Por cierto, debes mostrar un [repro], y modificar el título de tu pregunta para aclarar cuál es el error. Lee [ask].